# Add new translations in service AngulaJS and angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, resources, angular-translate

I'm using angular-translate (pascalprecht.translate) with angular 1.

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate

I have a variable that is passed in config to configure the resources/translations:

```
var resourcesEN =
{
    HOME: "Home",
    MENU: "Menu",
    MESSAGE: "Message"
}

$translateProvider.translations('en', resourcesEN);
```

At some point in my app, I receive from a server request new resources, and I need to add/extend my translations with them. The new resources need to be parsed and added inside a service (where the server request happened).

The $translateProvider can't be injected inside my service (only config), and the $translate service seems to not have a methode to add/extende my resources.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: how do you get the new resources from server you mentionned?

Comment: I get the resources in a data structure diferente from the typical key value pair used in the var resourcesEN in the above example. I need to parse that data. I was trying to put resourcesEN in a angular constante and them update that constant adding dynamically new entries. But it seems it does not refresh the object reference initially passed in the $translateProvider.